# Tslint error: The 'prefer-inline-decorator' rule threw an error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, tslint

After an Angular 9 upgrade, encountered the following error in the project:

Running `ng lint` throws the following error for every single .ts file in my app:

```
The 'prefer-inline-decorator' rule threw an error in '/path/to/my/project/src/app/app.component.ts':
TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined
    at Object.isParameterPropertyDeclaration (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:14561:83)
    at callbackHandler (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/codelyzer/preferInlineDecoratorRule.js:163:50)
    at callback (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/codelyzer/preferInlineDecoratorRule.js:218:9)
    at visitNodes (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:17774:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:18080:21)
    at callback (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/codelyzer/preferInlineDecoratorRule.js:219:22)
    at visitNodes (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:17774:30)
    at Object.forEachChild (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:18007:24)
    at walk (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/codelyzer/preferInlineDecoratorRule.js:221:18)
    at Rule.AbstractRule.applyWithFunction (/path/to/my/project/node_modules/tslint/lib/language/rule/abstractRule.js:39:9)
```

`ng --version`:

```
Angular CLI: 9.0.2
Node: 10.19.0
OS: linux x64

Angular: 9.0.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router
Ivy Workspace: Yes

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.900.2
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.900.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.900.2
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.900.2
@angular-devkit/core              9.0.2
@angular-devkit/schematics        9.0.2
@angular/cdk                      9.0.0
@angular/cli                      9.0.2
@angular/flex-layout              9.0.0-beta.29
@angular/material                 9.0.0
@ngtools/webpack                  9.0.2
@schematics/angular               9.0.2
@schematics/update                0.900.2
rxjs                              6.5.4
typescript                        3.7.5
webpack                           4.41.2
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
...

  "dependencies": {
    "@ag-grid-community/angular": "^22.1.2",
    "@ag-grid-community/core": "^22.1.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.2",
    "@angular/animations": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/core": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^9.0.0-beta.29",
    "@angular/forms": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "9.0.1",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/material": "^9.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/router": "9.0.1",
 
    "@mat-datetimepicker/core": "^4.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^12.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "ag-grid-angular": "^22.1.1",
    "ag-grid-community": "^22.1.1",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "bignumber.js": "^9.0.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.2",
    "date-fns": "1.29.0",
    "del": "2.2.2",
    "js-sha512": "^0.8.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
    "material-design-icons": "3.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ngx-uploader": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-webstorage": "^5.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "rxjs": "6.5.4",
    "text-mask-core": "^5.1.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2",
    "zxcvbn": "^4.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^9.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.0.1",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "^2.1.3",
    "@compodoc/compodoc": "^1.1.11",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^2.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.17.0",
    "angular-playground": "6.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "concurrently": "^5.0.2",
    "cypress": "^3.8.2",
    "eslint": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.0",
    "husky": "^3.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.6.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.1",
    "json-server": "^0.15.1",
    "karma": "^4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^3.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^2.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "^3.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.1",
    "karma-structured-json-reporter": "^1.0.1",
    "prettier": "1.18.2",
    "pretty-quick": "^2.0.1",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "start-server-and-test": "^1.10.7",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "^5.20",
    "tslint-config-airbnb": "^5.11",
    "tslint-config-prettier": "^1.18",
    "tslint-consistent-codestyle": "^1.16",
    "typescript": "3.7.5",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.6.0"
  },
  "false": {}
}
```

I could not find any instruction about this error. Removing the said rule in `tslint.json` file fix the issue, but skipping this is not an option due to the central codestyle ruleset of my company.

`ng build`, `ng serve` works fine, and using the app seems to be unaffected by this problem. Only the linter throws this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

1. `rm -rf node_modules/`
2. `rm package-lock.json`
3. `npm i`

Strangely enough, simple `npm install`˙and `rm -rf node_modules/` was not enough, I had to delete the package lock file as well.